# unlink image in folder using codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

i want to delete image from folder using unlink in codeigniter. I already succed delete data from database, but the image can't remove from folder. I got problem with the PATH of my folder image. This is my controller

```
public function single_delete($id) {
    // meload method di model
    $gambar = $this->input->post('userfile');
    $data = $this->admin_produk_model->delete($id, $gambar);

    // menampilkan alert jika data berhasil/gagal dihapus
    if ($data == TRUE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', '<strong>yeah..</strong>Hapus data berhasil dilakukan');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', '<strong>Oopsss..</strong>Hapus data gagal dilakukan');
    }

    // meredirect ke controller
    redirect('admin/produk/');
}
```

this is my model

```
public function delete($id, $gambar){

    // query delete
    $this->db->where('id_produk', $id);
    unlink('asset/user/img/produk/'.$gambar);
    $this->db->delete('produk');
}
```

This is my folder structure
[image]

i got this error
[image]

Comment: You have to change the permissions of the folder produk. That is not a codeigniter issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$gambar= 'file_name.jpg';
$path = './asset/user/img/produk/'.$gambar;
unlink($path);
```

OR

```
$this->load->helper("file");
delete_files($path);
```

Can also use File Helper to do file related operations. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: @AdiSatria You  need write access to the directory in which the files are located. You are deleting the directory content, so access to the file is not enough, need also write access