# Remove image from folder after deleting in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete the image not only in database, but in folder too.

this is my model

```
    public function delete($id)
        {
            if ($this->db->delete("np_gallery", "id = ".$id)) 
            {
            return true;
            }
        }
```

this is my controller

```
public function delete_image($id)
{
    $this->np_gallery_model->delete($id);
    $query = $this->db->get("np_gallery");
    $data['records'] = $query->result();
    $this->load->view('admin/gallery/gallery_listing',$data);
}
```

this is my view

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sl No</td>
                    <td>Tag</td>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php 
            $SlNo=1;
                foreach($records as $r)
                {
             ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <?php $image_path = base_url().'uploads';?>
                     <td><?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $r->tag; ?></td>
                     <td><img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>/images/gallery/<?php echo $r->picture;?>" style=" width:35%; height:100px;"/></td>
                     <td><a href="<?php echo site_url() . "/np_gallery/select_content/". $r->id?>" class="fa fa-pencil"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                         <a href="<?php echo site_url() . "/np_gallery/delete_image/". $r->id?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete')" class="fa fa-trash"></a></td>   
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
```

I succeed in deleting the data in the database, but the image in the folder are not also be deleted.

Comment: <?php unlink("image path") ?>

Comment: where should i put this code vivek

Comment: where u are deleting the image in controller u can apply a condition like `if image delete  than unlink("imagepath")` but u have to pass the `image name` also right now u r passing id only or you can get the image name from id in the controller, whatever you like :)

Comment: does that worked ?

Comment: no it doesnot work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unlink image in folder using codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297196/unlink-image-in-folder-using-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

```
foreach ($query_get_image->result() as $record)
    {
        // delete file, if exists...
        $filename = $image_path . $record->picture; 
        if (file_exists($filename))
        {
            unlink($filename);
        }

        // ...and continue with your code
        $this->np_gallery_model->delete($id);
        $query = $this->db->get("np_gallery");
        $data['records'] = $query->result();
        $this->load->view('admin/gallery/gallery_listing',$data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add some extra code in your controller:

```
public function delete_image($id)
{
    $image_path = base_url().'uploads/images/gallery/'; // your image path

    // get db record from image to be deleted
    $query_get_image = $this->db->get_where('np_gallery', array('id' => $id));
    foreach ($query_get_image->result() as $record)
    {
        // delete file, if exists...
        $filename = $image_path . $record->picture; 
        if (file_exists($filename))
        {
            unlink($filename);
        }

        // ...and continue with your code
        $this->np_gallery_model->delete($id);
        $query = $this->db->get("np_gallery");
        $data['records'] = $query->result();
        $this->load->view('admin/gallery/gallery_listing',$data);
    }
}
```

Note: alternativelly, you can do it inside your model delete() method instead. Consider where it better fits your applicaction needs.