# i wnt to remove file from folder after delete in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete the image not only in database, but in folder too.

this is my controller

```
public function delete_image($id)
{
    $image_path = base_url().'uploads/images/gallery/'; // your image path
    // get db record from image to be deleted
    $query_get_image = $this->db->get_where('np_gallery', array('id' => $id));
    foreach ($query_get_image->result() as $record)
    {
        // delete file, if exists...
        $filename = $image_path . $record->picture; 
        echo $record->picture;
        if (file_exists($filename))
        {
            unlink($filename);
        }
        // ...and continue with your code
        $this->np_gallery_model->delete($id);
        $query = $this->db->get("np_gallery");
        $data['records'] = $query->result();
        $this->load->view('admin/gallery/gallery_listing',$data);
    }
}
```

i am able to delete from database but not from the folder

Comment: Check your folder to see if image exists, or if there is any permission issue on the folder. What error message are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove image from folder after deleting in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862932/remove-image-from-folder-after-deleting-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

please use this code in your delete function

remove image path in your $filename.

```
$filename = $record->picture; 
unlink("uploads/images/gallery/".$filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (file_exists( base_url().'uploads/images/gallery/'.$filename))
    {
        unlink( base_url().'uploads/images/gallery/'.$filename);
    }
```